# How do I have a running task in a thread pool yield to another task that's currently queued?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java-threads

I have a task that does some work, then recursively calls itself:

```
void taskA() {
    // logic
    Future future = pool.submit( () -> taskA() );
    // logic (block on future.get())
}
```

I submit the recursive invocation to a thread pool (size 1), at which point the running task is blocked because the queued-up invocation doesn't get a chance to run. Is there a way to have the ExecutorService yield its thread to temporarily put aside the blocked task in order to allow the queued up task to run in its place?

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your code to use CompletableFuture and what we commonly call the continuation pattern.

Instead of using Future.get, you should use CompletableFuture and call the code that depends on the result of Future.get inside CompletableFuture.thenRun and friends.

You can also have a look at ForkJoinPool. It is made for tasks that are collaborating together and that can be interdependent.

The ThreadPoolExecutor isn't designed for that kind of use. It's rather made for tasks that are mostly independent from eachother.
It isn't forbidden, but as you have seen, you can quickly lock up yourself if your pool hasn't enough threads. If you want to keep using ThreadPoolExecutor in the way you have done in your example, you must have at least as much threads as there are possible recursions.